# AWS EFS deadlock with zero burst credit balance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs

I have been using EFS for a couple of months now but realized today that the Burst Credit Balance has become zero, rendering the EFS unresponsive. The current metered size is 2.6 GiB. 
I understand increasing size by copying dummy data would generate additional credit balance and potentially make EFS accessible. But the problem is that the EFS directory has become so slow that even commands like ls are taking ages.
Is this a deadlock situation? Are there ways to make EFS accessible again or at least recover data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credits are continually replenished.  The problem is that you are consuming them at that same rate, which leaves you without enough capacity to handle your workload.

Stop accessing the filesystem, or at least reduce the demand you are imposing on it, and performance will recover automatically.

Adding data increases the size of your system, which increases the *rate* at which credits are replenished.

EFS performance scales linearly with the total size of the stored data.